# variable isnt updating as the code loops through

Tags: vbscript

Ive written some code that loops through text files in a folder and updates them with an addiotnal header "TREATMENT_CODE" and then appends a code to the end of each line within each text file. The code is taken from the txt file name. Ive set this as a variable called TCode. The problem Im having is that the TCode variable isn't changing after the first loop through. Can anybody help? Thanks

Please excuse all of the msgbox lines, just me using them to figure out whats going on.

Code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO, FLD, FIL, TS
Dim strFolder, strContent, strPath, FileName, PosA, TCode, rfile, Temp, dataToAppend, fulldata,          wfile, TempArr, i
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 

 'Change as needed - this names a folder at the same location as this script
  strFolder = "C:\Users\User1\OneDrive -         Company/Documents\Temporary_delete_every_month\CRM_combiner_macro\Looping_test\files to amend"

 'Create the filesystem object
 Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get a reference to the folder you want to search
 set FLD = FSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

'loop through the folder and get the file names
 For Each Fil In FLD.Files
   'MsgBox Fil.Path
 'If UCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(Fil.Name)) = ".txt" Then

strPath = Fil.Path
'msgbox strPath
'strPath = Replace(strPath,"""","")

'msgbox  strPath

 posA = InStrRev(strPath, "\") +1

 TCode = "|"  &  Mid(strPath, posA, 11)

 msgbox "this is TCode " &  TCode

 Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

 'msgbox "next file to amend" & strPath

Set rfile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath, ForReading)                'File opened in Read-only mode

While Not rfile.AtEndOfStream

  temp=rfile.ReadLine()

If rfile.Line=2 Then                             

    dataToAppend = "|TREATMENTCODE"
ElseIf rfile.Line=3 Then
    dataToAppend =  TCode 
End If
fulldata = fulldata & temp & dataToAppend & "|||"
Wend

rfile.Close

fulldata = Left(fulldata,Len(fulldata)-2)

Set wfile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath, ForWriting)                'File opened in write mode

tempArr = Split(fulldata,"|||")

For i=0 To UBound(tempArr)
wfile.WriteLine tempArr(i)
Next
wfile.Close
Set fso= Nothing

  'End If

'Clean up
Set TS = Nothing
Set FLD = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
set rfile = Nothing
set wfile = Nothing
set tempArr = Nothing
set Temp = Nothing
set TCode = Nothing

Next

MsgBox "Done!"
```

Comment: What is the value of TCode that is staying the same?

Comment: The TCode is taken from the txt file name, so the code is supposed to loop through add the txt name at the end of very line in the txt file. After the first loop the TCode stays the same for every txt file thereafter

Comment: Without proper indentation, I find this code hard to read.

Comment: Sorry, I’m a bit of a newbie to code writing

Comment: Everything else is working as intended, it just doesn’t seem to be clearing the initial TCode value after the first loop through

Comment: The mag box This is TCode & TCode even displays the correct TCode

Comment: So it is actually calculating the correct TCode, it is just not appending it to the lines of the file correctly. Perhaps you could show some input and output.

Comment: I probably can’t show before and after as the txt files contain customer information for the company I work for

Comment: Although, I can mock something up

Comment: In your Clean up code at the end of the loop, try setting dataToAppend to Nothing.

Comment: `TCode` is not saved directly in the output file, instead a `tempArr` is used and it can be potentially empty. To ensure the output, add debuggin messages to see `fulldata` and `tempArr(i)`

Comment: Thanks, Homeyboy Wilson - setting datatoappend didn't work.

Comment: You got exactly the same results, or different results?

Comment: tried adding debugging msgs but it produces errors. I tried msgbox fulldata and msgbox tempArr?

Comment: same results Honeyboy

Comment: its something to do with the fulldata. if I set set fulldata to nothing it breaks the script. I checked the output and every files is being overwritten wit hthe data fro mthe first file

Comment: Right before the While Not rfile.AtEndOfStream loop starts, try setting fulldata = ""

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I added “full data = nothing” to the clean up section at the end of the code